# Android Camera in Background OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, background, camera, frame

I'm new in openCV for Android and I need a app that do image processing (detect lines of an image) that works in background.

I have already made an app that does all the image processing that I need (with jni) but it doesn't work in background and it uses CvCameraViewListener2 (which doesn't work in a service I think)

For what I have already searched the best way is to create a service with surfacetexture but I don't understand how. (Have already seen panoramaactivity)

So can I "transform" the work I've done in a service (with CvCameraViewListener2) working then in background? Or do I have to do everything from 0 with surfacetexture?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with OpenCV and Android Camera. It's not that difficult to begin with. I used JNI to process frames. Things you need to do.

- Use android.hardware.Camera
- Create a class which extends SurfaceHolder.Callback and Camera.PreviewCallback

In `OnPreviewFrame` method, get `byte[]` data which would most probably in the format of `NV21` (YUV) so you need to convert it to RGBA or whatever that suits your needs. Once you get the frame data, you should create a background thread to process the frame in order to not hinder the UI thread.

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    if (data == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "data is null");
        return;
    }

    int expectedBytes = previewWidth * previewHeight *
            ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.NV21) / 8;

    if (expectedBytes != data.length) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Mismatched size of buffer! Expected ");

        mState = STATE_NO_CALLBACKS;
        mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(null);
        return;
    }

    if (mProcessInProgress) {
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
        return;
    }

    if (mState == STATE_PROCESS) {
        mProcessInProgress = true;

        processDataTask = new ProcessPreviewDataTask();
        processDataTask.execute(data);

    } else {
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
        return;
    }

}
```

---

```
private class ProcessPreviewDataTask
        extends
            AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(byte[]... datas) {
        mState = STATE_PROCESS_IN_PROGRESS;
        Log.i(TAG, "background process started");
        byte[] data = datas[0];

        /* JNI Call here */

        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
        mProcessInProgress = false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mState = STATE_PROCESS;
        threadInProcess = false;
    }
}
```

I have a sample code which you can use. You can find it [here](https://github.com/jayrambhia/AsynCamera).

Comment: I have one more question..

I have 2 programs: 

1 - This that does the image processing stuff
2 - Another one that does other stuff

I need that the program 2 calls the 1 to make the image processing stuff (just like a service because I don't want to show nothing and the program 2 should continue working)

So I believe what I really need is program 1 as a service. 

So runs program 2 that calls program 1 service and then when program2 is closed, it closes the service 1. 

The question here is how can I make this program 1 works as a service?

Comment: That is really confusing. You want to run image processing part as a service? Does that include only image processing or accessing the camera too?

An app that I made does something similar. It creates long exposure photos. So when the user presses start button, the image processing part starts and when the user presses the stop button, it stops. Also, included pause and resume there. 

Are you looking for something similar?

Comment: I need an app that accesses the camera and does the image processing's stuff. (real time processing)

That app/service or something like that needs to continue working while another app does another things.